# Scheduling algorithm which minimizes maximum lateness is optimal (it finds a feasible schedule, if one exists)

Tags: algorithm, real-time, scheduling, proof

I need to understand why if a scheduling algorithm A minimizes maximum lateness, then A is optimal (it finds a feasible schedule, if one exists).

I searched on the web for a long time, but without any success.
Can you tell me which ingredients I need to prove that please?

---

EDIT
The viceversa is not true: if A is optimal, it can happen that A is not able to minimize the maximum lateness.

Comment: The schedule is feasible if and only if the maximum lateness is zero. Does that help?

Comment: Hello @DavidEisenstat thank you for your reply. It should be feasible if the maximum lateness is less or equal to zero. I'm looking for a proof of the above sentence (I edited it). It's a sentence of my professor.